# graphQl issue: OR condition not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, graphql

I'm having an issue with an Or condition in my graphql statement.  It returns all orders where the Order_Status__c field is 'Quote', but not 'Waitlisted'.  There are no errors, just the additional data is not returned. I've looked at graphQl examples and what I have seems to be correct.  If I remove the contition for 'Quote', Waitlitsted orders are returned by the query.  The query seems to stop after retrieving 8 records, even though there are additional records that are of either status.  Any ideas?

````
    query: gql`
    query ordersByProgramDateId($orderId: ID, $programDateId: ID) {
        uiapi {
          query {
            Order__c(
                where: {
                and: [
                  { Id: { ne: $orderId } }
                  { Program_Date__c: { eq: $programDateId } }
                  { or: [
                    { Order_Status__c: { eq: "Quote" } } 
                    { Order_Status__c: { eq: "Waitlisted" } }  // this isn't used for some reason
                  ]}
                ]
              },
              orderBy: { Name: { order: ASC }}
            ) {
              edges {
                node {
                  Id
                  Name {
                    value
                  }
                  Order_Status__c { value }
                  Account__r { Name { value } }
                  Linked_Order__r { Name { value } }
                  Order_Lines__r ( where: {
                                    and: [
                                      { Order_Line_Type__c: { eq: "Accommodation"}} 
                                      { or: [
                                                  {Order_Line_Status__c: { eq: "Open" }},
                                                  {Order_Line_Status__c: { eq: "Confirmed" }}
                                                  ]}
                                      ]
                                  },
                                  orderBy: { Contact_Name__c: { order: ASC }}
                                  ) {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        Id
                        Name { value }
                        Order_Line_Status__c { value }
                        Program_Date_Product_Descriptive_Name__c { value }
                        Contact_Name__c { value }                           
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: '$variables',
    operationName: 'ordersByProgramDateId',
}) ```
````

Comment: Can you add totalCount to see what was total number of results? Note by default graphql only returns 10 records. You can add pageSize to increate the count

Comment: @MohithShrivastava the issue was due to graphQl only returning 10 records by default.  Once I updated my query to include "first: 200, upperBound: 2000" it worked fine.

Comment: It is great that you have found and solved the issue yourself. But please remember to add that as an answer to your own question and accept it later.

Comment: As @RenatoOliveira said make sure to add as an answer.